# YQL Weather statement not showing certain objects such as Sunrise, Sunset and Wind chill

Tags: javascript, xml, yql

Hi there I am using the statement

```
    SELECT * FROM rss WHERE url="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/SPXX0239_c.xml"
```

I get the data for a 5 day forecast, with date, icon, temp and text which is great. However I want to pull additional info such as wind chill, sunrise/sunset and feels like temp. I cannot see them in the request??

Here is my callback for the data

```
    window['wCallback_2'] = function(data) {
// Get todays weather forecast
     var info = data.query.results.item.forecast[0];
     var code = info.code;
$('#wData_current .wDate_d').append('<TD>' + info.date) + '</TD>';
    $('#wData_current .wDay_d').append('<TD>' + info.day) + '</TD>';
    $('#wData_current .wIcon_d').append('<TD> <img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/' + code + '.gif" width="80" height="80" title="' + info.text + '" /> </TD>');
$('#wData_current .wText_d').append('<TD>' + info.text + '</TD>');
    $('#wData_current .wHigh').append('<TD>' + info.high + '&deg;' + u + '</TD>');
    $('#wData_current .wLow').append('<TD>' + info.low + '&deg;' + u + '</TD>');
```

};

Comment: The data is included in the XML but it's all part of a `yweather` node, i.e. `yweather:wind` contains the wind info, `yweather:astronomy` contains the sunrise and sunset. I'm not sure how you'd access that node in your current context, but the data is there in the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rss` table only gives you what is inside the `<item>` element(s).  Since RSS is plain old XML, the `xml` table can be used instead.

```
SELECT * FROM xml
WHERE url="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/SPXX0239_c.xml"
AND itemPath="rss.channel.*"
```

Would give you a `data` object structured like:

```
{
 "query": {
  …
  "results": {
   "title": "Yahoo! Weather - Lanzarote, SP",
   …
   "location": { … },
   "units": { … },
   "wind": {
    "chill": "19",
    "direction": "20",
    "speed": "32.19"
   },
   "atmosphere": { … },
   "astronomy": {
    "sunrise": "7:29 am",
    "sunset": "8:19 pm"
   },
   "image": { … },
   "item": {
    "title": "Conditions for Lanzarote, SP at 8:59 pm WEST",
    "lat": "28.95",
    "long": "-13.6",
    "link": … ,
    "pubDate": "Mon, 15 Apr 2013 8:59 pm WEST",
    "condition": { … },
    "description": … ,
    "forecast": [ … ],
    "guid": { … }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

To access the sunrise time, you could use `data.query.results.astronomy.sunrise`.

Comment: This answer is absolutely spot on.  After changing the request it now retrieves this info. Thank-you so much!